# textinput.needsSoftKeyboard does not work (air for android)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, android-softkeyboard, android-input-method

I have a textbox in my project wich is  in a movie clip.
I have designed a new keyboard for my app and i dont want to see android keyboard when i tap on that textBox in movie clip.

textinput.needsSoftKeyboard

Is false for that textbox but when i touch the textbox the android keyboard pop's up.

What is the solution??